# attic ventilation baffles

Tags: roof, roofing

I can find this product [online in Europe](http://www.monier.co.uk/products/product-catalogue/product-range/product/redvent-eavesvent-3.html), but so far not in the US.

Is there an eave ventilation baffle that is designed to be laid across the rafters (when the installer is up on the roof before decking is installed) and nailed to the rafters' sky-facing edge, rather than inserted between the rafters from inside the attic and stapled or nailed to the side face of the roof rafter?

P.S. These baffles serve a dual purpose: 1) They provide a clear airway and 2) they are weathertight.

Comment: I don't understand your "weathertight" statement. No attic baffle should ever see weather. Airflow, sure.

Comment: There are roof designs where there is no overhanging eave, but a gap above the fascia board for air intake. That gap area should be weathertight if possible. The baffles I'm searching for have a rubberized flap that goes over the fascia board and flaps that lap baffle to baffle, making them weathertight against wind-driven rain.